# Why does this sentence need a prepositon [in]?

Tags: measure-expressions

> *Whatever is wholly deprived of light is **in** complete darkness.*

Why not 'wholly deprived of light ***is*** complete darkness' ?

Answer (score 9):

How can you conclude that "Whatever is wholly deprived of light" is *darkness* ? It clearly means that when a thing is deprived of light, it will remain **in** darkness. Something cannot be darkness. It can be placed in darkness. Darkness is not an object. Darkness is just the state of absence of light.

Comment: Ah! You beat me by few seconds.

Comment: Sorry. Speed of "light" :P

Comment: Haha! Way to go!

Comment: Thank you. I hope colona found the answer he was looking for.

Comment: Why is it "speed of light" and not "speed of darkness"? :p

Comment: Because the speed of darkness is equal to the speed of receding light, isn't it ? :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not be "complete darkness", because [*darkness*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/darkness) is a noun that can mean

> 1. the state of being dark, without any light
>
>    - *Her face was in darkness.*

It would *be in* this state, not *be* this state. For example, if you are talking about a bedroom, the bedroom would still be a bedroom. It would not cease to be a part of a building. There are two relevant uses of the word [*in*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/in_1):

> 9. used to describe physical surroundings
>
>    - *He was sitting alone in the darkness.*
> 10. used to show a state or condition

Note that *darkness* as used in that example, and your example, can mean something closer to "the places that are dark" than "the state of being dark".

What you *could* say is that

> Whatever is wholly deprived of light is complete**ly dark**.

because *dark* is an adjective.